# Electret microphone and microphone amplifier with a bipolar transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

The circuit to the right in fig. 1 is a CE that amplifies the Vin signal from an electret microphone (input to terminal J1-2). The output impedance of the electret microphone is about 20 kΩ (the output of the electret microphone is the D and S terminals of a JFET; see the model in figure 2, where the R and C external to the capsule correspond to R6 and C1 on the amplifier). The Vout output (J2-1 terminal) will be attached to the node between C2 and R5 (i.e., the potentiometer has the upper and middle terminals connected). For BC549C use β = 500 and the remaining parameters given in the header.

In the header the information given to me are as follows:
[image]
Figure 1 and figure 2:
[image]

[image]

I need to calculate \$I_{C},V_{CE}\$ of polarization in the transistor Q1 and the DC voltages of the entire circuit.

I did not understand the statement. I did not realize what the microphone is and what the amplifier is. And I do not know how the final circuit is to be able to do the math and where that output impedance is located.
I would appreciate if someone could make a drawing of the complete circuit and put me the calculations of the parameters that ask in the statement, I am very confused and I am beginner. It's been several days since I've looked into this problem and I do not know what to do. You are my last hope!

Comment: I expect that the output is taken from the wiper (middle contact) of the pot, not from the C2/R5 junction.  If it was taken from that point, there would be a dot where the lines cross above the pot.

Comment: "I need to calculate IC,VCE of polarization in the transistor Q1 and the DC voltages of the entire circuit." - why?

Comment: *But my problem is that I've never seen such a complex circuit in front of me* OK, then why *I need to calculate ....* ? It just does not add up. Either you have learned something about electronics already and you should be (almost) able to do this **OR** you indeed have no clue but then it makes no sense to give you this assignment. The circuit is just a common emitter circuit so look that up and get studying.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I've been studying every day, believe me. All I have learned is to be self-taught. My problem with this circuit is that I do not understand how the final circuit is drawn. If I do not understand the statement, I can not even try to solve it and put it in the post for you to see.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Because that's what the teacher asks for in the statement. I know I have to put the capacitors in an open circuit to do the polarization. My problem is that I'm not realizing the statement and how the final circuit is. Can you help me?

Comment: @PeterBennett I know I have to put the capacitors in an open circuit to do the polarization. My problem is that I'm not realizing the statement and how the final circuit is. My problem is that I did not realize how the final circuit is designed with everything the teacher imposes on me. Can you help me? Can you make a drawing with all the information in the statement so I can try to solve the polarization and put it here?

Comment: The schematic for the DC operating point of Q1 has 4 resistors and 1 transistor.

Comment: No idea what you mean with "polarization in the transistor" I guess you mean biasing conditions. As I mentioned: common emitter, so start here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html and determine how the circuit is **biased**, meaning, how much DC current is flowing. Capacitors cannot pass DC so for this calculation the capacitors are not present, leaving R1, R2, R3, R4 and T1. Step two: small signal equivalent circuit. You know the biasing now so you know gm, put it in the small signal circuit. Also add the capacitors.

Comment: @sstobbe For the initial circuit (of the statement) do I have to consider 1 BJT only or 1 BJT and 1 FET?

Comment: @FakeMoustache I know how to calculate these parameters. I do not understand is if I have to consider the initial circuit as just a BJT or a BJT and a FET. And why do I need the output resistance of the microphone?

Comment: It says: *The output impedance of the electret microphone is about 20 kΩ* That is the part **inside the capsule**. If you had to consider that JFET also, how would you do that (calculate output impedance and such) ? Can you ? No because there is no data for the JFET. Instead it says you can assume it to have a 20 kohm output impedance.

Comment: @Carmen González, yes the FET and BJT are independent for DC analysis (the input is ac/capacitively coupled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to calculate IC,VCE of polarization in the transistor Q1...

For DC analysis all capacitors can be ignored because they are effectively open circuit, and inductors are a short circuit. So the equivalent circuit for Q1 is:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Nqf1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First calculate the bias voltage at junction of R1 and R2. If we assume that Base current is negligible then this is just a simple voltage divider whose division ratio is (R2+R1)/R1. 12v / ((22kΩ+2.7kΩ)/2.7kΩ) = ~1.31V. V<sub>BE</sub> is 0.6V so Ve is 1.31V-0.6V = 0.71V. The current passing through R3 must therefore be 0.71V / 220Ω = ~3.23mA.

I<sub>E</sub> = I<sub>B</sub> + I<sub>C</sub>. If the transistor isn't saturated then I<sub>C</sub> = I<sub>B</sub> * 500 and I<sub>C</sub> is almost equal to I<sub>E</sub>. The voltage across R4 is then ~3.23mA * 2.2KΩ = ~7.1V. 12V - 7.1V = 4.9V between Collector and Ground, and V<sub>CE</sub> = 4.9V - 0.71V = 4.19V. This is safely above the saturation voltage, confirming that the transistor is not saturated and has the specified current gain.

> ...and the DC voltages of the entire circuit.

The only other DC voltage that might need calculating is between the electret microphone and R6. If we assume that 20kΩ is the FET's DC resistance then you simply have a voltage divider with 2.2k and 20k.

Comment: How do I know if the transistor is in the saturation zone? My teacher defined the parameter Vce sat | = 0.2 V, but I do not know how to use it.